# Where does Notes Widget Catalog install new plug-in JAR files?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes

I am using a Widget Catalog to deploy plug-ins to users. For most users, this works and the associated JAR files are automatically installed into the {Notes-Data}\Workspace\applications\eclipse folder. But for a couple of users, the widget catalog attempts to install the JAR files into the {Notes-Program}\framework\shared\eclipse folder - which in turn fails since the users do not have OS permission to write files to this folder.

I guess the question is - how does the Notes/eclipse client decide where to install jar files deployed from the Widget Catalog? Is this a setting defined in a client file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependent on the install type of the client. Multiuser-installs force plug-in installation into the {Notes-Data}\Workspace folder, whereas if you install the Single User Client (opt. with Designer and Admin Client), it will also install plug-ins into the {Notes-Program}\framework\ folder.

Some Plug-Ins, esp. those installed though a MSI Installer (like the Connections Files Plug-In), may write into the {Notes-Program}\framework\ folder too.

HTH